# PHP is breaking HTML

Tags: php, html

When I have PHP in my file, the page shows blank and when looking at the source it shows that their is totally no tags on the page. When I remove my PHP the form shows just fine, but when the PHP is there.

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$subcontent = $_POST['subcontent'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

if(empty($content)){
    echo "<p>Create a new post</p>";
}
else{
    echo "<p style='color:green;'>success</p> " . $content;

$time = date("j, n, Y"); 

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "admin", "pass", "db");
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from Articles");
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO Articles (Title, subcontent, Content, Date) VALUES ('$title', '$subcontent' ,'$content', '$time')");


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head><title>Post a new article</title></head>

<body>

       <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter post Title"/>
            <input type="text" name="subcontent" placeholder="Enter sub-content"/>
            <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Enter content"/>
            <input type="submit" value="post"/>
        </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Blank screen >>> Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: what do you want to get from this query > mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from Articles");

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're missing a `}` at the end of your `else` statement

Answer (score 0):

cchapman990 is correct. I'd recommend reviewing your PHP error settings though, as they seem to be suppressed and seeing errors will make debugging a lot easier.

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE );
display_errors( 1 );
//etc.
?>
```

This can also be set globally within your php.ini file.